# How can I make the transition speed for divs the same using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to transition divs in and out when clicked. The first issue I'm having is, after page load, the first div doesn't fade in at the same time as the first div fades out. This causes the background to show while the clicked div fades in.
The second issue I'm having is that the transition speeds differ from div to div. Some are really fast and others are slower. Here is the [webpage](http://www.imcadams.com/indexnew.html#). Here is the jQuery code:

```
/**
 * @jQuery for Slideshow
 */

$("#home_splash1").show();

$('#btn2, #btn2-2').click(function(e) {
    $('#home_splash1, #home_splash3').fadeOut('2000', function() {
        $('#home_splash2')
        .css('visibility', 'visible')
        .fadeIn('2000');
    });
});

$('#btn1, #btn1-2').click(function(e) {
    $('#home_splash2, #home_splash3').fadeOut('2000', function() {
        $('#home_splash1')
        .css('visibility', 'visible')
        .fadeIn('2000');
    });
});

$('#btn3, #btn3-2').click(function(e) {
    $('#home_splash1, #home_splash2').fadeOut('2000', function() {
        $('#home_splash3')
        .css('visibility', 'visible')
        .fadeIn('2000');
    });
});
```

Comment: Include the relevant HTML within your post.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using `.css('visibility')` with `.fadeIn()` when `fadeIn` automatically takes care of the making hidden elements appear?

Comment: I looked at your actual code, and it looks like you are using strings as the duration instead of integers in some cases.

Comment: ding ding ding... @jwatts1980 has the correct answer.  Anyplace the duration is not an integer, the default duration of `400` is used instead of the string `'2000'`.

Comment: Actually, you can use the strings `'slow'` and `'fast'` as a duration, too.

Comment: @harbichidian... look at the jQuery docs' examples again... the number is like `400` and the string is like `'slow'`... but you cannot pass the number as a string.

Comment: I down-voted this question for one reason... you posted code different than the actual code used, requiring us to dig through your site to see the root issue.  In the future, please follow the posting guidelines.

Comment: @Sparky if I remember correctly, I added `.css('visibility')` because it wasn't working otherwise. I thought it was weird too because `.fadeIn()` was supposed to take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jwatts1980 said, you have a mix between strings and integers as your duration.

I tested and as you said, didn't work. Once I opened your script and edited it locally it worked perfectly so change where you have `'2000'` to `2000`. Only strings that get passed as durations are `'slow'` and `'fast'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#home_splash1').show();

    $('#btn2, #btn2-2').click(function(e) {
        $('#home_splash1, #home_splash3').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $('#home_splash2').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });

    $('#btn1, #btn1-2').click(function(e) {
        $('#home_splash2, #home_splash3').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $('#home_splash1').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });

    $('#btn3, #btn3-2').click(function(e) {
        $('#home_splash1, #home_splash2').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $('#home_splash3').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Also a document ready function isn't required as you have this at the bottom of your page so it's going to load *after* everything else anyway.

Quote from jQuery API Docs:

> If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is used.

Comment: Using a DOM ready handler is a good habit and there is no downside to using it, even when it _might_ be superfluous.

Comment: @imcadams Please mark this as an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry about posting the wrong code. I tested it and it fixes the difference in speed between slides. It still behaves weird on the first slide change though. The first slide fades out and the new slide suddenly appears instead of fading in. Any idea how I can fix that? I have updated the [webpage](http://www.imcadams.com/indexnew.html#) for you to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you can pass when you call a jQuery animation function is known as a "callback" function: When this function you call is completed, "call back" to the callback function. In your case that means it gets called *after* the animation has completed *all* of its steps.

The [jQuery documentation for `fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) has more details.

To get to the point, you need to remove the `.fadeIn()` from inside the callback function, and have both the `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` run at the same time. Luckily jQuery animations are "asynchronous" functions, which mean they seem to complete instantly: As soon as you call `.fadeOut()` it "finishes" immediately and processing moves on to the next line. This means you can put lots of animations you want to happen at the same time right next to each other.

Changing your code to something like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5G9th/1/)) will give you the effect you want:

```
$('#show-splash-1').click(function(e) {
    $('#splash2, #splash3').fadeOut(2000);
    $('#splash1').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: This does not explain the observed inconsistency.  See comment by @jwatts1980.